# Detecting Audio File Bit Rate - Processing / Java

Tags: java, audio, processing

Trying to build a little app for sorting through audio files based on some of their properties. Have managed to grab the Sample Rate and Bit Depth using Minim but can't find anything anywhere for getting the Bit Rate?

Happy to look at taking the program to Javascript if needed but just desperate to find a method for detecting bit rate of a given file.

EDIT: Attempted to try and form an equation based off file size but cannot find a method for detecting MP3 file size either.

Comment: Hello Charles, you mention that you managed to grab both the Sample Rate and the Bit Rate but you can not grab the Bit Rate? Can you please correct your question? I suppose you got the Sample rate but need the bit rate? Are you using mp3 files?

Comment: Sorry for clarification I have the Sample Rate and Bit Depth just not the Bit Rate. I am using an MP3 for test, later will be moving to WAV and AIF etc

Comment: by the way, if the proposed answer has worked out for you could you please follow this guideline and mark it as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp)

You will need to download the jar, I managed to get it from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/jaudiotagger/2.0.3)

Go to Sketch -> Add File... and select the downloaded jar, it should be added in a folder named **code** within your sketch folder.

Assuming you have placed an mp3 file in your data folder named ***audio.mp3*** the following code should work, printing out the bit rate in the terminal.

```
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.*;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO;

void setup() {
  File f = new File(dataPath("audio.mp3"));
  try {
    MP3File mp3 = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read(f);

    MP3AudioHeader audioHeader = mp3.getMP3AudioHeader();
    println("" + audioHeader.getBitRate());
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

JAudiotagger supports a variety of file formats and you can use the relevant classes and methods for each one of these.

I suggest you take a look at the [javadoc](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/javadoc/index.html). Be careful of the examples though, [the one I used](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_id3.jsp) in order to answer your question seems to be faulty, as you can see I had to swap **getAudioHeader** with **getMP3AudioHeader**.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing me to this library! Looks ideal for this appreciate it. However, when trying to execute your code I've got a 'CannotReadException' error on the MP3File mp3 line. Bit confused as it's loading the file fine! EDIT Think I may have fixed it actually apologies

Comment: Ok slightly odd I can't get the code to work outside of the try/catch, any chance it can be put into a function?

Comment: Sure you can move the code to a function, you need the try catch though for reading the file, in case it does not exist or is not accessible. I moved the whole code from setup to a method String getBitRate(String filename){...} and it worked fine. What exactly are you trying to do?